# Using dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats [oracle]

Tags: oracle, optimization

I am using `dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats('%schema%')`

The process is working about 3 hours.

Objective: to optimize the current process.

Where do I see the time of collection of statistics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing to do is to trace the process that executes dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats and then profile the output. Then nobody has to guess.

```
SQL> select * from v$diag_info /* to get location of trace file */;
SQL> exec dbms_monitor.session_trace_enable(null, null, true, false, 'all_executions')
SQL> exec dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats('%schema%')
SQL> exec dbms_monitor.session_trace_disable(null,null)
```